# "Newest" list on SO is displaying old questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, question-lists

I have been observing strange behavior on Stack Overflow. In the question list, under sort="newest," I see a question that according to the page was asked one minute ago and has 0 answers and 0 votes. When I click on it and see the details, it turns out to be one day old with four answers. I have been facing this problem for two or three days now.

Comment: this is the right place. You should link to the question so others can verify this though, or even better, provide screenshots

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce this. Are you on the correct tab?

Comment: now i don't seem to reproduce the error either. however, thanks for ur consideration. i will remember Tobias suggestions of uploading screen shots in case i find any problem again.