# User name problem on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-norepro, user-accounts, users

I have been experiencing different kind of problems on Stack Overflow and I had posted a question on meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68891/newest-list-on-so-is-displaying-old-questions). But the experts could not reproduce the problem, neither could I. Today, when I opened Stack Overflow it was showing me Tassadaque's profile instead of mine (me and Tassadaque are on the same lan sharing single public IP address). When I clicked on his name to go to his profile, Stack Overflow showed me following page[image]

You can see that on the top bar it's showing my name (Muhammad Adeel Zahid), but in the details section it is showing the credentials of Tassadaque. This clearly is absurd, and it happens to me frequently. This could be the default authentication cookie of ASP.NET MVC!

**Edit** OK, this is the correct behavior if I view Tassadaque's profile after logging in. Now, I just closed all Stack Overflow tabs in my browser and in the new tab I opened the link http://www.stackoverflow.com. The screenshot below shows the result.
[image]

I had already logged into Google, but it is showing me that Tassadaque is logged in. Let me mention once again that we are sharing same public IP address on the LAN.

Comment: Where did you click his name at? Your screenshot looks like the expected behaviour, since you're viewing his public profile (shown on the page) logged in as you (shown in the top bar).

Comment: when i first open stackoverflow it shows tassadaque as logged in user. that is where i clicked his name. edited the question plz see 2nd screenshot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar problem at work. In our case it is related to the proxy server we use, which due to caching sometimes pulls the wrong page out, especially if you retrieve the home page or a question you viewed before. When you hit a new page you haven't viewed it tends to sort itself out.

I suspect this is the same problem you're having. We have done extensive testing, and apart from seeing someone else's rep and name in the top bar, once you navigate away to something new you're the right person again. I am not sure if SO can do anything to fix this, as it is controlled by local proxies outside of their control.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking at looks correct to me.  The top part is your information.  Below the StackOverflow logo, it gives you the heading for the page.  In this case that is the user name of the user's profile you're viewing.  Below that, it shows you the profile details.

What is not shown is the open id information and visited fields.  These are not public fields, so it is correct that you don't see them.

[image]

Comment: i edited my question plz have a look

Comment: your hand-drawn lines look very smooth. Are you using a Tablet?

Comment: Sorry @rchern, **-1**, that's a freehand *square*.

Comment: @Theun Squares have 3 sides of unequal length?

Comment: @Grace Note: Point taken! It's what then? A freehand mess of lines?

Answer (score 1):

What do you see in the address bar?

Is it something like this?

[image]

Here, I am logged in and looking at your profile.  Note the highlighted section of the address bar.

Comment: i edited my question. plz have a look